# BxSlider implementation issue with random slide control

Tags: jquery, bxslider

Due to issues running the excellent FlexSlider in Umbraco with the Slimmage set up, I had to replace it with BXSlider. This slider is not as good in my opinion and does some really weird stuff if on smaller screens or if you reduce the browser size. It will skip two slides on load, then once it's gone round once, it will reverse for a couple of slides then go forward for one then reverse again, totally random, and totally not what's required.  Below is the implementation I'm using. Can anyone spot anything wrong with it or suggest a good slider that will work with Slimmage?

Using BxSlider v4.1.2, JQuery v2.1.1 and Bootstrap v3.2.0

HTML

```
                <div class="row">
                                <div class="slider">
                  <ul class="bxSlider">
   <li>   
                                    <noscript data-slimmage="true" data-img-src="/media/1001/tigh-ruaraidh-1.jpg?center=0.52709359605911332,0.49&amp;mode=crop&amp;quality=90&amp;width=984&amp;heightratio=0.4634146341463414634146341463&amp;format=jpg&amp;slimmage=true&amp;rnd=130544148660000000" data-img-alt="Where time stands still"><img src="/media/1001/tigh-ruaraidh-1.jpg?center=0.52709359605911332,0.49&amp;mode=crop&amp;quality=90&amp;width=984&amp;heightratio=0.4634146341463414634146341463&amp;format=jpg&amp;slimmage=true&amp;rnd=130544148660000000" alt="Where time stands still"></noscript>
                                    <div class="sliderCaption">Where time stands still</div>   
                                </li>
   <li>   
                                    <noscript data-slimmage="true" data-img-src="/media/1002/tigh-ruaraih-from-garden.jpg?crop=0,0.017543859649122806,0,0.0678219940094138&amp;cropmode=percentage&amp;quality=90&amp;width=984&amp;heightratio=0.4634146341463414634146341463&amp;format=jpg&amp;slimmage=true&amp;rnd=130548450510000000" data-img-alt="Paradise in Scotland"><img src="/media/1002/tigh-ruaraih-from-garden.jpg?crop=0,0.017543859649122806,0,0.0678219940094138&amp;cropmode=percentage&amp;quality=90&amp;width=984&amp;heightratio=0.4634146341463414634146341463&amp;format=jpg&amp;slimmage=true&amp;rnd=130548450510000000" alt="Paradise in Scotland"></noscript>
                                    <div class="sliderCaption">Paradise in Scotland</div>   
                                </li>
   <li>   
                                    <noscript data-slimmage="true" data-img-src="/media/1017/applecross-bay-from-applecross-river-2.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;quality=90&amp;width=984&amp;heightratio=0.4634146341463414634146341463&amp;format=jpg&amp;slimmage=true&amp;rnd=130548512660000000" data-img-alt="Applecross Bay from Applecross River - 2.jpg"><img src="/media/1017/applecross-bay-from-applecross-river-2.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;quality=90&amp;width=984&amp;heightratio=0.4634146341463414634146341463&amp;format=jpg&amp;slimmage=true&amp;rnd=130548512660000000" alt="Applecross Bay from Applecross River - 2.jpg"></noscript>
                                    <div class="sliderCaption">Applecross Bay from Applecross River - 2.jpg</div>   
                                </li>

                  </ul>
                </div>                  
            </div>
```

JS

```
      $(function(){
        window.slimmage.readyCallback = function() {
        // Slider
            if($('.bxSlider').length > 0) {     
                $('.bxSlider').bxSlider({
                  mode: 'horizontal',
                  captions: false,
                  auto: true,
                  speed: 5000,
                  useCSS: true,
                  responsive: true,
                  controls: false,
                  infiniteLoop: true
                });
            }
        }
})
```

Comment: Another thing I noticed was every time the browser is resized, or the device orientation changed, then the pager items multiply. To the extend that on a 3 image slider there can be 18 pager points!